# Accessing the value of a radio button sliding among html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is this code that apears several times in my page:

```
<div>
   <input type="hidden" name="product" id="productF3" value="7">
   <div>
    <input type="radio" name="size" id="size_s" value="3"> small size
   </div>
   <div>
   <input type="radio" name="size" id="size_n" value="4"> regular size
   </div>
</div>
```

I have a problem getting the selected value, starting from the productF3 element.
Right now I'm using this code to solve my problem:

```
if($("#productF3").next().children("input[@name=size]:checked").val() != undefined) do something
else if($("#productF3").next().next().children("input[@name=size]:checked").val() != undefined) do something
else alert("Select a size");
```

But I want a more robust solution, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly change `$("productF3")` to `$("#productF3")`. Secondly why don't you use

```
$("#productF3").parent().find("input[type='radio'][name='size']:checked").val()
```

to get selected radio value?

Comment: The html code that i posted, appears several times on my page, so i need to be sure I get the value of the checked radio button that is next to "productF3".

Comment: You want radio buttons rather than checkboxes and according to http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/ "For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="checkbox"] instead." :radio has the same comments.

Comment: @Hubrus Check it now. @Chris You're right. I was confused by those `:checked` selectors :).

Comment: This line has an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string. If i use $("#productF3").parent().find(":radio[name='size']:checked").val(); If is selected the first radio button i get the correct value but if i check the second radio button, it returns undefined